# obfuscating javascript Error: Cannot read property 'type' of null

Tags: javascript, encryption, null, obfuscation

I'm experimenting with javascript obfuscating. I'm using https://obfuscator.io/ and https://javascriptobfuscator.com/Javascript-Obfuscator.aspx on both obfuscating it returns a error when trying to obfuscate this piece of code, why?

```
        document.body.onmousedown = function () {
            try {
                document.getElementById("moveItem").innerHTML = "";
                createdChart = false;
            } catch {
            }
        };
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null
```

Comment: The error is not related to this piece of code, as there is no `type` property being accessed.

Comment: the obfuscator seems to not like the try/catch. it works when you remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://obfuscator.io

> A free and efficient obfuscator for JavaScript (including ES2017).

Now check the syntax for `catch` in [ES2017 docs](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#prod-Catch).

> `catch` **(** *CatchParameter*[?Yield, ?Await] **)** *Block*[?Yield, ?Await, ?Return]

As you can see the parentheses are mandatory. That's why the JavaScript obfuscator cannot process it.